# How do you do non-numeric book editions in BibTeX?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I want to reference the book "An Introduction to Fluid Dynamics" by George Batchelor using BibTeX. The edition I'm using says it is the "First Cambridge Mathematical Library Edition 2000". This is not the first edition of the book, so I want to make the distinction between this version and the first, but I'm not sure what the correct way to input the edition into BibTeX is (it's not just a number like "First").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you have to follow a style guide that says otherwise, but I would literally typeset the edition's description. The "TeXnical" correct way to do so very much depends on the used bibliography style. BibTeX's standard styles (`plain` & friends) append "edition" to the contents of the `edition` field, other styles don't do so. [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) checks if the `edition` field contains a numeral and will append "edition" (or whatever term is appropriate for the chosen language) only if this is true. Here's an example using `plain`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Bat00,
  author = {Batchelor, George},
  year = {2000},
  title = {An Introduction to Fluid Dynamics},
  edition = {{First Cambridge Mathematical Library}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: And an example using `biblatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[abbreviate=false]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  edition = {1},
}
@book{Bat00,
  author = {Batchelor, George},
  year = {2000},
  title = {An Introduction to Fluid Dynamics},
  edition = {First Cambridge Mathematical Library edition},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: I did try just putting the edition essentially as you've done it, but with only one set of braces around it. The result is de-capitalised for some reason. Is this sort of thing the responsibility of the bibliography style?

Comment: @mjrussell: Yes, de-capitalisation is also style-dependend.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. But what does the extra set of braces do then?

Comment: @mjrussell: It prevents de-capitalisation by the style.

Comment: @lockstep: For me, using the 'plain' style with pdflatex, it does not prevent de-capitalisation, and I get exactly the same result as without the second pair of braces.

Comment: @mjrussell: Works for me. Anyhow, I added an example using biblatex, which I highly recommend.