# Alter or remove automatically appended string "edition" in bibliography

Tags: bibtex

Some of the standard bibliography styles, like `plain`, append the literal string *edition* to the value provided in the BibTeX database file.

For example, consider the following,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
  @book{tufte,
    title     = {The Visual Display of Quantitative Information},
    author    = {Edward R. Tufte},
    year      = {1983},
    edition   = {2nd},
    publisher = {Graphics Press}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \bibliography{refs}  
\end{document}
```

which outputs something like

[image: Output of MWE provided before]

Note how the edition has been changed from *2nd* to *2nd edition*.

**How can I change the value of *edition* in the output?**

I would like to be able to abbreviate this to *ed.*, for example. Getting rid of the string altogether [may also be useful](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17092). I'd like to stick with BibTeX if at all possible, but am open to alternative solutions.

One solution I am aware of is to take the contents of the generated `bbl` file and replace the `\bibliography` call in my TeX source by those, then editing them. I'd like to avoid such a manual and tedious step if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I definitely wouldn't get rid of the word "edition" without providing some kind of replacement. After all, bare strings such as `2nd` and `3rd` may be rather ambiguous if they're not accompanied by some kind of qualifier.

To shorten the string `edition` to just `ed.`, I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `plain.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `plain-ed.bst`. (Do not edit an original file of the TeX distribution.)
- Open the file `plain-ed.bst` in a text editor; the editor you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In `plain-ed.bst`, locate the function called `format.edition`. (In my copy of the file, the function starts on line 334.)
- In this function, change both instances of `" edition"` to `"~ed."`. Observe that the space in the original string gets changed to `~` in the replacement string.
- Save the file `plain-ed.bst`, either in the directory where the main tex file is located or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{plain}` to `\bibliographystyle{plain-ed}` and perform a complete recompile cycle -- latex, bibtex, and latex twice more -- to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

Comment: Thanks a lot, that absolutely worked like a charm! I'd like to clarify that I only asked about removing it so that I could put "~ed." in the BibTeX file, I fully agree with only having `2nd` be ambiguous. Finally, maybe a small addendum to your excellent answer: finding `plain.bst` can be done by running `kpsewhere plain.bst`, for example. It was located at `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/base/plain.bst` on my machine. This may be something you want to add. Again, I appreciate your detailed answer!

Comment: @Justastudent - You're most welcome! Just a very minor point: I think the name of the file search command is `kpsewhich`, not `kpsewhere`. :-) (Incidentally, I chose not to mention the `kpsewhich`-based search method in my answer as it works for *some* TeX distributions -- mainly, TeXlive and MikTeX -- but not for some other TeX distributions.)

Comment: Right, `kpsewhich` is more commonly known/used, I suppose. [`kpsewhere`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/kpsewhere) came with TeXlive on my system. I was not aware that it does not work with all TeX distributions, thank you for informing me!